# Is it possible and safe to migrate a P4 server from a Mac to PC? If possible is there a resource documenting the steps to do so?

Tags: windows, macos, perforce

I have a perforce server running on an old mac that I'm afraid may kick it at some point.
Not really wanting to have my next server be on a Mac but rather a PC I'd like to see if I can migrate it between different operating system. Maybe linux if not windows?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

> I'd like to see if I can migrate it between different operating
> system.

As I understand "migrate", no. It is generally not possible to transplant the image from one OS into an entirely different OS (e.g. from Linux to Windows).

Your best bet is to back up any data on the server, get a new Windows Server (your post), get it running, install comparable apps that are compatible with the new server.

Then restore your data to the new server.

Answer (score 0):

If by migration you mean encapsulating the Mac computer as a
virtual machine on Windows or Linux, then the answer is No.

It is only legal to run OS X in a virtual machine if the host computer
is a Mac. Therefore, it would be illegal to run OS X on Windows or Linux.

Your best bet would be to run the clone on a newer Mac.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is absolutely possible.  See this KB article: https://portal.perforce.com/s/article/2538

In a nutshell, you can take advantage of the fact that the entire database can be dumped to a checkpoint, which is completely portable even though the binary db files themselves aren't.  All of the archive files are in standard RCS/gzip formats that are easily portable between platforms.

If you're migrating from a case-sensitive Mac platform (you said "old" but not exactly how old...), I'd suggest migrating to Linux rather than Windows so you don't have to deal with case sensitivity mismatches -- these are possible to work around, but better avoided if possible.